# Phalcon не видит класс Mailer\Manager

Tags: php, phalcon

**composer**:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phalcon-ext/mailer": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

**controller**:

```
$mailer = new \Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Manager($this->config->sendmail);
$message = $mailer->createMessage()
                  ->to('mail@gmail.com', 'Vanik')
                  ->subject('Hello')
                  ->content('World');
if(!$message->send()) {
   $this->flash->error('Письмо не отправлено');
   return $this->view->form = $register;
}
```

Ошибку выдает : что не видит `\Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Manager`.
Устанавливал **SwiftMailer** строго по инструкции с *github*.

В чем причина?

Comment: А можете выложить полный stack trace ошибки?
`composer update` делали?

Comment: Делал.
Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Manager' not found in C:\OpenServer\domains\allahelper.loc\app\controllers\AuthController.php on line 98